# Creating a common dictionary in python taking key value pairs from multiple pair of lists

Tags: python, dictionary

How can I create a big dictionary in Python taking key value pairs from multiple pair of lists. For example, we have 6 lists, namely *key1,val1,key2,val2 and key3,val3*. Now I want to create a dictionary containing **all keys from key1, key2 and key3** and **corresponding values from val1, val2, val3** respectively.
for example:

```
val1 = ['3/12/2017', '12/18/2017', '12/18/2017', '12/12/2017']
key1 = [32, 45, 107, 150]
val2 = ['2000-03-13', '2014-11-31']
key2 = [166, 244]
```

I want the dictionary as given below:

```
big_dict = {32: '3/12/2017', 107: '12/18/2017', 45: '12/18/2017', 150: '12/12/2017', 244: '2014-11-31', 166: '2000-03-13'}
```

How can this be done?
Thanks

Comment: On what basis, would the key items would be assigned to the value items? It doesn't seem to be ordered.

Comment: If any answer helped you then you can try considering accepting that answer....see https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers#:~:text=Choose%20one%20answer%20that%20you,the%20answer%2C%20at%20any%20time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple answer would be this, Although there are much efficient ways to do this.

```
val1 = ['3/12/2017', '12/18/2017', '12/18/2017', '12/12/2017']
key1 = [32, 45, 107, 150]
val2 = ['2000-03-13', '2014-11-31']
key2 = [166, 244]

big_dict = {}

big_dict.update(dict(zip(key1, val1)))
big_dict.update(dict(zip(key2, val2)))
```

Or combine lists before and do a one-liner

```
keys = key1 + key2 # Make sure they are unique however or else dict() will show incorrect results
values = val1 + val2

big_dict.update(dict(zip(keys, values)))

print(big_dict)
```

Answer (score 3):

Using [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) and simple concatenation:

```
big_dict = dict(zip(key1+key2, val1+val2))
```

If you have an unknown number of key and value lists, use [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) and [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
from itertools import chain

big_dict = dict(zip(chain(*key_lists), chain(*val_lists)))
```

Answer (score 1):

try this code:

```
a=(dict(zip(key1,val1)))
b=(dict(zip(key2,val2)))
d = a.copy()
d.update(b)
```

Answer (score 0):

add all the lists to a common list and automate the process, as such:

```
combined_dict = {}

values_lists = [ val1, val2 ]
keys_lists = [ key1, key2 ]

for itr in range(len(keys_list)):
    for list_itr in range(len(keys_list[itr])):
        combined_dict[keys_list[itr][list_itr]] = values_lists[itr][list_itr]
```

Comment: This seems to needlessly complicate things.

Answer (score 0):

I would concat the lists, and by using `zip` merge it into keys and values (dictionary).

```
val1 = ['3/12/2017', '12/18/2017', '12/18/2017', '12/12/2017']
key1 = [32, 45, 107, 150]
val2 = ['2000-03-13', '2014-11-31']
key2 = [166, 244]

keys = key1 + key2
vals = val1 + val2
d = dict(zip(keys, vals))

print (d)
# {32: '3/12/2017', 45: '12/18/2017', 107: '12/18/2017', 150: '12/12/2017', 166: '2000-03-13', 244: '2014-11-31'}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extend the list and the zip them and create a dictionary like below

```
val1 = ['3/12/2017', '12/18/2017', '12/18/2017', '12/12/2017']
key1 = [32, 45, 107, 150]
val2 = ['2000-03-13', '2014-11-31']
key2 = [166, 244]

key1.extend(key2)
val1.extend(val2)

newdict = {k: v for k, v in zip(key1, val1)}

print(newdict)
```